# changing text type to object type fails on unsupported parameters

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index on `elastic-search 6.5.1` with a field `data` that It's current type is *text*. it contains a Json string.

I'm trying to change the type of the field to `object` but getting an error

```
PUT my-index/_mapping/doc
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": { 
      "properties": { 
        "data": { 
          "type": "object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm getting an error with root_cause:

```
{
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {doc={properties={data={type=object}}}}]"
 }
```

I searched the web regarding this error, But the only answers I found are syntax errors, Which I don't think I have (Hope)

Is it the correct approach? - changing text type to object type in order to get "real" indexed json?. Is there another data type that I should use instead? If not, Why getting this error?